# CodeBlocks doesn't tell me whats wrong and I am really stuck

Tags: codeblocks

I have been using Code::Blocks recently, and not for a whole lot of time so I'm still getting used to it, but I have a problem with my current project and the only thing I am being told is "Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 9 second(s))"

Im not sure if I have a setting that I need to mess with to get better output in the build log or if my program is just that confused :P

here is a link to my code: http://pastie.org/private/ynxnai8ddjs7plhnw3i2w

there are some things commented out near the bottom, that is the latest thing I added so I tried removing it to see if that was the problem but it seems not

Answer (score 0):

[image]maybe you're looking for Settings -> Compiler -> Global compiler settings -> Other settings -> Compiler logging: Full Command Line -then you see exactly what and how codeblocks calls external programs (like the compiler, the debugger, the compiled program)

Comment: I looked and I have that setting already on, if anyone is able to figure out what is actually wrong with my program I would be most appreciative

Comment: if that's really your settings, i refuse to believe that its only saying "Process terminated~~"...

Comment: http://puu.sh/jKoZK.png see, I have no reason to lie, Im just as confused as you probably are